# ASP .NET Core Web API load 32bit library in IIS leads to BadImageFormatException with 32bit enabled

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, 32bit-64bit, asp.net-core-3.1

So I want to run a ASP .NET Core 3.1 Web API in IIS which needs to load a 32bit library. SO I just enabled the 32bit feature in the ApplicationPool. Also is see in the TaskManager that the process is 32bit. Also I set installed the 32bit dotnet sdk and set the PATH variable to the 32bit version. But always I want to execute a method which loads the 32bit assembly I get an `System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly` error which means that the process is 64bit??
When I start without the IIS it works just fine.

For building I used the `win-x86` runtime

Comment: Unfortunately `BadImageFormatException` can be throwed for scenarios more than bitness mismatch. Reveal the call stack of the exception and that might tell more about the cause.

Comment: @LexLi So this is the complete CallStack: pastebin.com/DHVE6f1z

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix my issue by installing [Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable](https://aka.ms/highdpimfc2013x86enu)

Comment: Then it can be explained. This `SPCApi` assembly is a mixed mode assembly produced by VC++ compiler, which unfortunately depends on VC++ runtime. Other examples include the popular SQLite assembly, https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki